# Why can't I move the mini iTunes player between Spaces?

Tags: itunes, snow-leopard, spaces

[image: image of mini itunes in case I'm being really obscure with my terminology]

On snow leopard, I am unable to move the mini-itunes player between spaces.  For any other app (including the full library showing iTunes) I move windows between spaces by clicking and holding the app title then using the keyboard shortcuts to move between spaces.  However when doing this with the smaller player, it's determined to be left behind.  Does anyone else experience this or have suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

**Brief Specs**

- OS X 10.6.8
- iTunes 10.5.3(3)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experiencing that issue here (OS X 10.6.8/iTunes 10.5.3). But one thing you can try is to drag the window to the edge of your screen toward the space to which you wish to switch. After a brief pause, you will slide over to that space, hopefully bringing the iTunes mini window with you.

Comment: It doesn't work to drag to the edge either (again the full window does), I'm also using 10.5.3

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this problem... have you tried restarting iTunes and/or your computer? In any case, you have two other methods to do it: either drag the window to the left or right edge of the screen and hold it there until the space changes, or do a four-finger swipe up and drag the window to the desired space.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately after the double restart it's still sticky to the main space.  It doesn't work to drag to the edge either (again the full window does).  Haven't got a trackpad so can't try the gesture unfortunately.

Comment: How about launching Mission Control from the dock or from Applications?

Comment: Another possibility: move the non-small window to another space, then ensmallen it.

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder No Mission Control in Snow Leopard.

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder that's one option, was just hoping there'd be an easy fix :L  Ahh well, hardly the biggest inconvenience I'll ever face =)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see you were on 10.6!